# How to index with list of indices in a multidimensional array in numpy/pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have an two multi-dimensional arrays of shape (1,169,5,1+4+4). One contains data, and the other contains zeros that is to be filled.

```py
>>> preds = np.random.random_integers(0,500,(1,169,5,1+4+4))
>>> filtered_preds = np.zeros((1,169,5,1+4+4))
```

For context the dimensions represent the following:

- batch size
- number of grid cells
- number of anchor boxes
- predictions (Confidence score, bounding box coords, number of classes)

I have a third flattened array of shape (169) that contains indicies of the best anchor box

Which looks like the following:

```py
>>> best_bboxes = np.random.random_integers(0,4,(169,))
```

In order to prevent using loops, my first instinct was to try the following to place the confidence values:

```py
>>> filtered_preds[:,:,best_ab_idx,0:1] = preds[:,:,best_ab_idx,0:1]
```

However, upon inspecting the array, I do not get the disired output as the shape of `filtered_preds[:,:,best_ab_idx,0:1]` is (1,169,169,1)

I guess my question so far is, how do I get values from my prediction array with the size of the second dimension and use the value of the third dimension to get the desired value?

I'm still a bit new to array indexing, so any help would be appreciated.

Note: I am using PyTorch but gave my examples in NumPy as it follows the same principle.

Edit:

Here is a solution of what I am trying to acheive using a loop:

```py
for idx,i in enumerate(best_bboxes):
    filtered_preds[:,idx,best_bboxes[idx],0:1] = preds[:,idx,best_bboxes[idx],0:1]
    filtered_preds[:,idx,best_bboxes[idx],1:5] = preds[:,idx,best_bboxes[idx],1:5]
    filtered_preds[:,idx,best_bboxes[idx],5:] = preds[:,idx,best_bboxes[idx],5:]
```

Comment: Your last block of code errors when I run it. "IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 5"

Comment: Fixed! Sorry about that. Used the 5 as the maximum for random num when I meant 4.

Comment: Also, it's odd that you enumerate over `best_bboxes`, but then you only use `idx` and not `i`. I'm mentioning this in case it's a mistake.

Comment: You're right I probably should have just used `i` to represent the anchor box index, I just gravitated toward the `best_bboxes[idx]` since I generally have worked with a lot of C++. Thanks for pointing out where I could have simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by the description of what you want to achieve, but I can simplify your given solution with the following.

```
seq_idx = np.arange(best_bboxes.size)
filtered_preds[:, seq_idx, best_bboxes, :] = preds[:, seq_idx, best_bboxes, :]
```